# Setting ShowParameterPrompts property when returning from a drill through report

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS 2012, I have a Main Report that takes 1 parameter, a dropdown. I have a drill through report that is displayed from a Main Report.  When the user is viewing the drill through report, I added a link on the drill through report that goes back to the main report.  I use the same parameter value so that the main report is displayed before the drill through report was selected.

The main report displays correctly, but the paremeter area is hidden when the user comes back from the drill through.

I read that there is a `ShowParameterPrompts` property but I cannot find where to set it.

Is there anyway to set this property from the subreport so the parameter area is showing?

**UPDATE**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Action tab, make sure you select the `Go to report` option. If you specify the report this way rather than a URL, SSRS will use the appropriate report viewer controls.

You should see something like `...RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=...` in your URL after you click on a drill-through.

The settigs should look like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Since this isn't working, let's try the URL method instead. Try this in a browser first to get the URL right and then specify it in the reports. To add the parameter in the URL after ".rdl" add "&rp%3a", then the name of the parameter, "=", and the value. So in your case:

```
= Globals!ReportFolder & "/SurveyResults.rdl&rp%3aSurveyName=" & <expr>
```

Of course the expression at the end there would be the value for the parameter. If your survey names have spaces, you'll need to URL encode them by replacing the spaces with "+" or "%20".

Comment: I added a screen shot of my `Go to report` dialog.  But with this configuration, when I go back to the main report, the parameter prompts are hidden.  I would like them to be shown.

Comment: The expression is just so the file path is not hard-coded.  If the RDLs are moved to another folder, it will go to the correct folder.  it is just this: `= Globals!ReportFolder & "/SurveyResults"`

Comment: @GloriaSantin thanks for the clarification. I added another edit.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I still get the error (ItemNotFound).  When use the original expression that returns the user to the main report but the parameter section is hidden, the url is a mass of characters nothing like the url that I would expect.  This is only part of the ending:  `SurveyResults&ExecId=0qnhmfywgkdped551nehf355&PingId=cakcc3` It seems like I could just set the Report Manager website to always show the parameter prompt.